# Obtain platform's path separator using Boost.Filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

Is there a way to obtain the platform's path separator character using [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem)? By path separator, I mean `/` for Unix and `\` for Windows.

I already know I can use `boost::filesystem::path::operator/` to concatenate two paths together with the appropriate separator character. But I just want either `/` or `\`.

I also know I can use `#ifdef _WIN32`, but I'd prefer that Boost.Filesystem tell me the appropriate separator character.

EDIT:
I want to use [version 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3) of the Boost.Filesystem API, as used in Boost 1.48.

Comment: D'oh! I was looking for an API that would directly give me the path separator, and didn't think of simply using: `boost::filesystem::path("/").native()`

Comment: Can someone confirm that `boost::filesystem::path("/").native()` returns `"\\"` on Windows?

Comment: Just so you know, Windows accepts `/` as the pafh separator.

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks, that renders my question moot for what I'm currently working on. But I'm still curious about the behavior of `boost::filesystem::path("/").native()` on Windows.

Comment: On WinXP, with VS2010, boost 1.48.0, the return value is "/".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of version 1.57, Boost now has a better solution, that is just constant `char` / `wchar_t` ( dependent on different platforms ): `boost::filesystem::path::preferred_separator`.

Read http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Operating-system-examples for more information. There are even more system-dependent features in it.

Simple example:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << boost::filesystem::path::preferred_separator << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: A quick look through the boost source reveals that boost just uses an ifdef to get the seperator during the preprocessor stage.
In this instance there is no need to use boost but also, if they are on a non-standard filesystem on a *nix box then boost will incorrecly assume /.

Answer (score 14):

It seems like [`boost::filesystem::path::make_preferred`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-make_preferred) is the ticket:

> Effects: The contained pathname is converted to the preferred native
>   format. [Note: On Windows, the effect is to replace slashes with
>   backslashes. On POSIX, there is no effect. -- end note]

Example:

```
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;
bfs::path slash("/");
bfs::path::string_type preferredSlash = slash.make_preferred().native();
```

Comment: New URL http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-make_preferred

Comment: On windows this will fail to compile, as native() will return std::wstring. That's irrelevant for the purposes of this question though.

Comment: @AI0867: Thanks, I replaced `std::string` with `bfs::path::string_type` in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but it looks like you should be able to use this on a recent boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << boost::filesystem::slash<boost::filesystem::path>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, `slash` no longer seems to be part of the API.