# How to get platform-specific path separator in C++?

Tags: c++

How can I get the platform-specific path separator (*not* directory separator) in C++, i.e. the separator that is needed to combine multiple paths in a list (e.g. `PATH` environment variable).

Under Linux, this would be `:`, under Windows `;`.

In other words, I am looking for the C++-equivalent of Python's `os.pathsep`, Java's `path.separator` or PHP's `PATH_SEPARATOR`.

If Boost provides such a function that would be fine, as we are using it in our projects anyway. If not, I guess any other solution would be good.

All I could find (here and elsewhere) were either just ways to retrieve the directory separator (i.e. `/` vs. `\`) or related to other languages than C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain platform's path separator using Boost.Filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384477/obtain-platforms-path-separator-using-boost-filesystem)

Comment: @awoodland: Really? Did you read the question?

Comment: @Nick - Oops, sorry I read the phrase "path separator" a lot and remembered that question - definitely not a duplicate then

Comment: Is a preprocessor directive not sufficient? `#ifdef _WIN32 const std::string os_pathsep(";") #else const std::string os_pathsep(":") #endif`

Comment: Well, somehow yes, but I'd prefer not to have to bother with this in my own code at all (similar to not having to deal with whether the directory separator is `/` or `\\`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per comment, a possibility would be to use the preprocessor:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
const std::string os_pathsep(";");
#else
const std::string os_pathsep(":");
#endif
```

Comment: Agreed.  We're talking about 5 lines of code, here.  You could have written this 100 times in the time it took to google it and ask a question on SO.  Not everything requires a highly-engineered, elegant and sublime solution.

Comment: Many platform dependent things can boil down to a few lines of code. Nevertheless, there are libraries (like the abovementionend APR, I was hoping for Boost as well) that provide this functionality and make sure that future platforms are properly taken care of as well without me taking care of this. I was just suprised that many other languages (or libraires for those) provide this, but C++ does not.

Comment: As I'm sure you're aware, these libraries are generally dependent on people dedicating their spare time to improvement. Why not have a go yourself and get something added to the boost::filesystem library?

Comment: @Nick Sure, I guess I'll ask on Boost mailing list next. Somehow, I guess there might be some reason (rather than an oversight) why this is not part of one of the libraries...Let's see

Comment: Well, obviously there is really no other choice (apart from @Nick suggestion of APR), so I guess I have to go with this solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

The only portable way beyond the use of the preprocessor that I can find would be through the Apache Portable Runtime:

[`apr_filepath_list_merge`](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__filepath.html#ga8316896ab8e3901f9711d9d4cc89b373) and
[`apr_filepath_list_split`](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__filepath.html#gaf259849de62ac172dde7dcbe73421500)

You could have a look and see how these are implemented but I'm guessing it would just be a preprocessor definition.

Comment: Using the APR just for this would probably be overkill however...!

Comment: I just checked the code. APR has platform-dependent implementations (seperate source files) in which the appropriate character is hard-coded within the functions.